# How to print Integer in quotes

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to print out from `System.out.println();` the output should looks like

```
"12345", "example", "12345_simple"
```

`example` is a constant word, so i figured it out
but the number `12345` is built inside a `for` loop...

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

How can I output this built number with quotes around it?

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript to me.

Comment: @user3321558 Java and Javascript are quite different beasts. It looks like you're writing Java.

Answer (score 2):

Print quotes around it?

```
System.out.println("\"" + i + "\"");
```

Comment: You can also use single quotes iirc:
System.out.println(' " ' + i + ' " ');
should give the same results because the compiler will treat them as characters.

Comment: @TerryChern: I'm pretty sure that gives numeric addition instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Sorry, I spaced it out so that it would look clearer, it should be: System.out.println('"' + i + '"'); the compiler is smart enough to know that you're concatenating characters and not doing math (polymorphism).

Comment: @TerryChern I'm afraid that even after your clarification this is still incorrect. If you try compiling and running the following (Java6, Mac) on your setup I expect you'll see 73 printed: public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println('"' + 5 + '"');
  }
}

Comment: Oh that's very interesting; when I tried doing that with a String it was smart enough to know to concat. The escape sequence version works with everything though. This is really good to know.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, they don't work. My statement inside the forloop looks something like this writer.write(i+, ","+alias). i+ is the incremental value which prints every time. so place + in front of i doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're saying is you build up the number `12345` in a `for` loop, so if you just put double-quotes around it you'll get a result like this...

```
"1""2""3""4""5"
```

Which is not what you want. Rather, you want simply `"12345"`. In this case, maybe something like this will do the trick...

```
String builtNumber = "";

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
  builtNumber += i;
  }

System.out.println("\"" + numberOutput + "\"");
```

This will create a `String` that contains the number `12345` (or for as many numbers as you specify). Once the `String` is created, it will output it with the double-quotes around it.

Of course, you could also just print out the quotes before and after the `for` loop, which is an alternative solution that should achieve the same result...

```
// the first quote
System.out.print("\"");

// the number
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    System.out.print(i);

// the second quote
System.out.print("\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way also

`System.out.print('"');`

`System.out.print(234);// you can have for loop here`

`System.out.print('"');`